# Logging of ip address, transaction id or session id in Mojo::Log

Tags: perl, mojolicious

I make use of simple logging in mojolicious application. I want to extend logging by some information. This could be ip address or transaction id or session id.
What I do before is writing for each log level one helper like this:

```
$self->helper( 'info' => sub {
 my $self=shift;
 my $msg=shift;
 my $ip=$self->tx->remote_address;
 $self->app->log->info("[$ip] $msg");
});
...
$self->info("Login failed of user $user.");
```

I would like to modify format of logging output so I can make use of generic log function which will add any additionally values I need and without lot of helpers for each log level.
Basic call of:

```
$self->app->log->info("Login failed of user $user.");
```

should also give log entries like

```
[Sun Jun  8 11:09:12 2014] [info] [127.0.0.1] Login failed of user Tim.
```

I try do do it by change log format but anything I do is ignored.

```
$self->app->log->format(sub {
 my ($time, $level, @lines) = @_;
 return "[$time] [$level] [$self->tx->remote_address] @lines.\n";
});
```

I know there is Log4Perl in combination with Mojolicious. But I want to keep it simple as possible.

Answer (score 3):

I got this going pretty quick with using Mojolicious::Lite;

To start off, shift a log to someplace you can find quickly.

```
use Mojo::Log;
my $log = Mojo::Log->new(path => '~/log/mojo.log');
```

Then try this, set the remote address variable outside of the sub first.

```
# $r_ip = remote ip address
my $r_ip = $self->tx->remote_address;

$self->app->log->format(sub {
     my ($time, $level, @lines) = @_;
     return "[" . localtime(time) . "]  [$level] [$r_ip] . join("\n", @lines) . "\n";
 });
```

The format can been seen at:
http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojo/Log

Answer (score 0):

There is a [possible to log a unique id per request/response?](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mojolicious/oWaU4YffyB4/s4pPrSkoAJ8J) thread on the Mojolicious mailing list, where Sebastian/sri - the author of Mojolicious - answers:

> Simple answer: You can't, Mojolicious is async by design and there may
>   be thousands of concurrent requests active at any given time.
>
> Complex answer: If you limit your application (through the server) to
>   handling only one request at a time and don't use any real-time web
>   features (not that it would make much sense if you can't handle
>   concurrent requests), you could subclass Mojo::Log to customize the
>   message format and store a global unique id for every new request.

The other (currently accepted) answer does exactly that: It removes all concurrency and uses a global variable. That'll start breaking down when you start using the real-time Mojolicious features.