# Mojolicious / Perl - Getting IP from packet?

Tags: api, perl, mojolicious

I've written an API using the Perl 'Mojolicious' framework that recieves requests from other web servers via CORS, however I'm having trouble extracting the IP address of the **requesting server**.

Extracting headers like `X-Forwarded-For` only gives the IP address of the client? Is there any way in Perl or Mojolicious to extract the source IP from the IP packet itself?

Using the inbuilt Mojolicious `$self->tx->remote_address` method doesn't work because my API web server sits behind an Nginx reverse proxy.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24104937/logging-of-ip-address-transaction-id-or-session-id-in-mojolog

Comment: The remote_address function returns the client IP, not the IP of the server calling my API.

Comment: The "server" calling your API is the client.

Comment: Actually now it's showing 127.0.0.1, probably because my API web server is running behind Nginx.

Comment: You need to configure nginx to stick the real client IP address into some other environment variable then

Answer (score 2):

I use own helper `src_addr`:

```
use Net::IP::Lite;

$app->helper( src_addr => sub {
  my $c = shift;
  my $xff = $c->req->headers->header('X-Real-IP') // $c->req->headers->header('X-Forwarded-For') // '';

  if($xff) {
    for my $ip (reverse split(/[\s,]+/, $xff)) {
      next if ! ip_validate($ip);
      return $ip;
    }
  }
  return $c->tx->remote_address;
});
```

In nginx:

```
    location / {
            proxy_read_timeout 300;
            proxy_pass http://localhost4:54329/;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto "https";
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-HTTPS 1;
    }
```