# How to get IP address in Mojolicious?

Tags: perl, mojolicious

I want to get the IP at each login for a user.
I've tried:

```
my $ip_address = $controller->tx->remote_address;
```

but it's getting the host server IP.
How should I get it?

Comment: In your other now-closed question about this you brought up `Mojolicious::Plugin::ClientIP`... Did that not work out?

Comment: no, that did not work out

Comment: @andrei -- see if following [ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35312054/mojolicious-perl-getting-ip-from-packet) is applicable for your case

Comment: Could [`Mojolicious::Plugin::RemoteAddr`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojolicious::Plugin::RemoteAddr) be a solution for your problem?

Answer (score 5):

If you're behind a reverse proxy `$c->req->headers->header('X-Forwarded-For')` will give you what you're looking for but the proper fix is to "tell your application about it by setting the environment variable `MOJO_REVERSE_PROXY`"

Or if you're using Hypnotoad enable proxy support via config

```
# myapp.conf
{hypnotoad => {proxy => 1}};
```

"This allows Mojolicious to automatically pick up the `X-Forwarded-For` and `X-Forwarded-Proto` headers."

Once you do that `$c->tx->remote_address` will automatically give you the `X-Forwarded-For` value and if you wanted the original IP you'd use `$c->tx->original_remote_address`

source: [Mojo Cookbook](https://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojolicious/Guides/Cookbook#Reverse-proxy)

Comment: Thanks, I'm using `morbo` to test and needed some headers anyway, so: `my $headers = $c->req->headers->to_hash;
    my ($remote_addr,$proxy_addr) = split(/,/, $headers->{'X-Forwarded-For'}) ;
    $log->debug('in index remote address is ' . $remote_addr );`

Comment: Please, remember there can be any number of proxies from 0 to multiple.